# Is there a way to identify which part of a SVG TextPath was clipped

Tags: javascript, svg, ecmascript-5

I have a SVG textPath shown below.

```html
<text class="text" dominant-baseline="middle" style="font-size: 0.3em">
<textPath class="text-path" href="#2abd837a-0">Cats and dogs</textPath>
</text>
```

This textPath is *correctly* showing the clipped based on the length of the path referenced by #2abd837a-0.

How would I go about using javascript to find the length of the clipped and invisible text? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the text length by using the `getComputedTextLength` method.
you can calculate the path length by using the `getTotalLength` method.

```js
let textLength = elText.getComputedTextLength();
let pathLength = abd837a.getTotalLength();
let invisibleTextLength = textLength > pathLength ? textLength - pathLength : 0;

console.log(textLength,pathLength,invisibleTextLength)
```

```html
<svg viewBox="120 100 100 100">
<path id="abd837a" d="M 130 110 C 120 140, 180 140, 170 110" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
<text id="elText" class="text" dominant-baseline="middle" style="font-size: 16px">  
  <textPath class="text-path" href="#abd837a">Cats and dogs</textPath>
</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping.